# Can AI win in any way other than dominance?

Tags: civilization-5

After seeing a very disappointing lack of followthrough from the AI in my latest deity game, I'm wondering if anyone has proof that the AI is capable of any of the following

- Achieving a diplomatic victory (by buying city states)
- Achieving a cultural victory
- Achieving a spaceship victory
- Conquering the capital of another civilization that was on a different continent than it started

The last one seems possible but unlikely, while the other three appear to be impossible from what I have seen.  Has anyone seen any of these happen?

Comment: I have seen an AI complete 3 of 5 required social policy trees about 2/3 through a game, so it was getting reasonably close to a cultural victory. Haven't seen one win though.

Comment: @deceze Hopefully it would be smart enough to build the Utopia project, but given its record with the Apollo project I'm not so sure.

Comment: The AI is also technically capable of winning on score when time runs out, if you count that as a victory path.

Comment: I see that more as a player failure than an AI success.

Comment: Hopefully this question will become obsolete with the AI changes coming in the next major patch...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can confirm a very good effort for a science win from AI. They have built an Apollo Program and several ship parts. It was a really nice end-game race, as I was beelining tech tree to rush United Nations for diplomatic. It was my first successful immortal game so I didn't want to lose it just to see if AI can win, but it certainly looked like they could.

On the other hand I had another game where I was hopelessly lagging behind a runaway AI on science. They entered future era, when I was still in mid-industrial. But they were so busy conquering the world that didn't bother to go for science victory. So it might be that if AI is set up to achieve dominance they won't go for other types if victory.

Comment: This is a good point, it might pick a way that it wants to win and ignore the others.

Comment: If you saved the Immortal game could you rerun the end part?

Comment: The XML files seem to support this theory.  It mentions AI's choosing a strategy for how to achieve victory, so the big hole might just be that it isn't fluid in switching between victories and it isn't capable of planning an amphibious assault.

Comment: @bwarner The AI has significantly improved in its ability to switch victory types in various patches. It is now be much more likely to switch to a more feasible victory type than it was 2 years ago.